# Django 1.8, How to completely reset migrations?

Tags: python, django, migration

I want to completely reset migrations and database.

How do I delete the migration files of "auth" app.

If I type any command related to `migrate`, the following error happens:

> django.db.migrations.graph.NodeNotFoundError: Migration auth.0007_user_lend_to dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('account', '0007_deal_is_completed')

Comment: You should ask about the actual problem you're trying to solve and not the workaround

Comment: I can delete migration files related to apps I created , for example, products app and deals app. However, I don't know where them of "auth" app are because I didn't create it intentionaly. So please teach me how to delete the migration files.

Comment: what about this `python manage.py migrate --fake`?

Comment: Thank you , but the same error happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you want migration from scratch.First recreate database.Then

```
find . -path *migrations* -name "*.py" -not -path "*__init__*" -exec rm {} \; # make sure to be in your projects path
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deleted most of migration files, but not deleted them of "auth" app. Do you know how to delete them or where they are?

Comment: No need of delete it.